# How to fix "System.InvalidOperationException"

Tags: c#, sql, database, authentication, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a login page on ASP.Net web app. But i am getting this error when i click the login button: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type UserTable is not part of the model for the current context."

Here is the code

```
        public ActionResult Authorise(UserTable user)
        {
            using (DBModels db = new DBModels())
            {
                var userDetail = db.UserTables.Where(x => x.username == user.username && x.password == user.password).FirstOrDefault();
                if(userDetail == null)
                {
                    user.LoginErrorMsg = "Invalid Username or Password";
                    return View("Index", user);
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["id"] = user.id;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: The error explains that the DBModels class does not have a UserTables property. Either create Usertables in your DBModels constructor or create it separately and set it to DBModels db.

Comment: @JReno i have UserTable in DBModels db

Comment: If you are using edmx based configuration, check your connection string. Probably the entityconnectionstring is different.

Comment: If you add db to your Locals or Watch, does it have the UserTables property?

Comment: @JReno no and it doesnt work if i put `UserTable`

Comment: Are you sue you are giving entityconnectionstring and not just plain sqlconnectionstring?

Comment: @MatJ How do i know if its entityconnectionstring

Comment: You have 2 problems. 1 is that your db.UserTables.Where is using UserTables PLURAL. This might be a different namespace from UserTable and you'll want to see which you need.

2nd is that DBModels does not have UserTables in its instance. If 1 is supposed to be using UserTables PLURAL, make sure that your UserTables constructor initializes the UserTables variable. Or set db.UserTables to new UserTables() or something.

Comment: Check your app.config or web.config as applicable. If you have an edmx file, then your connection string should have section with`metadata=res://*/edmx_file.csdl|res://*/edmx_file.ssdl|res://*/edmx_file.msl;`

Answer (score 0):

Long shot: you have a mismatch between `UserTables` and "UserTable".

This would happen if you had

```
[Table("UserTable")]
public class UserTables
```

AND the table in the db is is not called `UserTable`.

Comment: The table name is UserTable . the db name is DBModels. i followed tutorial and it's UserTables and im not sure why

Comment: the name of the tables in the database is UserTable

Comment: If you log in to the database **using the connection string** that you use for the code does it have the `UserTable` table?